# How to SELECT all rows within a certain date/time range with a certain timestamp step size in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, timestamp

I have a table that contains sensor data with a column `timestamp` that holds the unix timestamp of the time the sensor measurement has been taken.
Now I would like to `SELECT` all measurements within a certain date/time range with a specific time step.
I figured the first part out myself like you can see in my posted code snippet below.

```
// With $date_start and $date_stop in the format: '2010-10-01 12:00:00'

$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT sensor_1 
                                     FROM sensor_table 
                                     WHERE timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP($date_start) 
                                       AND timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP($date_stop) 
                                     ORDER BY timestamp");
```

Now is there a convenient way in MySQL to include a time step size into the same `SELECT` query?

My table contains thousands of measurements over months with one measurement taken every 5 seconds.

Now let's say I would like to `SELECT` measurements in between `2010-10-01 12:00:00` and `2010-10-02 12:00:00` but in this date/time range only `SELECT` one measurement every 10 minutes? (as my table contains measurements taken every 5 seconds).

Any smart ideas how to solve this in a single query?
(also other ideas are very welcome :))

Comment: So you want only one result within the range of 10 minutes? How do you determine which is the "correct" one? First, last, highest, lowest within that range of 10 mins?

Comment: No, I actually want the sensor values that have been taken between '2010-10-01 12:00:00' and '2010-10-02 12:00:00' (that is a whole day) BUT as the measurements are saved into the database with only a 5 seconds time difference that are way too many results. So I still want the measurements of the whole day but at a larger time step (e.g. 10 minutes and not the 5 seconds the measurements are saved into the DB). Could I make it a bit clearer? If not, I try to explain it again with a better example. Thank you for answering :)

Comment: I'm asking within that 10 minute window, where there are 120 entries - which one of those do you assume to be the right one? The first one, the highest one? Lowest one?

Comment: Well, it will start with the first one that has been taken in the specified range and then the next one after 10 minutes. Then again the next one after 10 minutes (until the '2010-10-02 12:00:00' has been reached). Sorry for not being clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you take one measurement every 5 seconds, the difference between `$date_start` and the first matching measurement cannot be greater than 4. We then take one entry every 600 seconds (allowing for some discrepancy from clock to clock...)

```
SELECT sensor_1 
  FROM sensor_table
 WHERE timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP($date_start) 
       AND 
       timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP($date_stop) 
       AND
       ((timestamp - UNIX_TIMESTAMP($date_start)) % 600) BETWEEN 0 AND 4 
 ORDER BY timestamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not elegant, but you can do:

```
SELECT s.sensor_1 
FROM sensor_table s
WHERE s.timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP($date_start) AND
      s.timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP($date_stop) AND
      s.timestamp = (SELECT MIN(s2.timestamp)
                     FROM sensor_table s2
                     WHERE s2.timestamp >= 60 * 10 * FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(s.timestamp) / (60 * 10)) AND
                           s2.timestamp < s2.timestamp >= 60 * 10 * (1 + FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(s.timestamp) / (60 * 10)))
                    )
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

This selects the first in each 10 minute period.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could use a simple cursor in plSQL

```
    CREATE TABLE StoreValuesId
    (
      valueId int primary key;
    )

    CREATE OR REPLACE procedure_store[date_start date,date_stop date]
    DECLARE date_startUpdated date , date_stopUpdated date , date_diff TIME(7) = '00:10:00'
    IS 
    BEGIN
SELECT date_start INTO date_startUpdated;
SELECT date_stop INTO date_stopUpdated;
    IF timestamp BETWEEN date_start and date_stop then
    INSERT INTO StoreValuesId values(timestamp)

    date_startUpdated=DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, date_diff), date_startUpdated);
    date_stopUpdated=DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, date_diff), date_stopUpdated);
    END IF
    COMMIT;
    END
```

Then again the syntax might be wrong but I hope you'll get the idea (haven't played with sql in a while)